# Reading all output lines of a console application working from a win32 application using C#

Tags: c#

I have a win32 application and I start a console application using the following code:

```
public void ExecuteDecript(int element)
{
    string toquen = TaskList[element].MakeToquen();
    string cmdexePath = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
    string myApplication = @"d:/SL3-xgold/tools/oclHashcat-lite-0.05/" + toquen;
    string cmdArguments = String.Format("/K {0}", myApplication);

    OCLProcess = new Process();
    OCLProcess.StartInfo.FileName = cmdexePath;
    OCLProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdArguments;
    OCLProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    OCLProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    OCLProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputHandler;

    OCLProcess.Start();
    OCLProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();            
}

private static void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(outLine.Data);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I read all the lines of the console application but the last one which is only read when I close the console application. Any theory about it?

Answer (score 1):

The above code should be running without any problem. However the problem must likely to be at the Console application maybe at the last write you do `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine` so it will not be read until the application *terminates* and so flushes that stream. If that doesn't help please post some code for your console application to diagnose the problem further.

Comment: hi, thanks but this is the problem, the cosole appilication.I'm not in order to control the cosole application (oclhashcat-lite-32), and the code of this application is unknown for my....

Comment: @Tony: In that case don't use process.BeginOutputReadLine() instead use the process.StandardInput stream and read the buffer by standardInput.Read and build a strings from that buffer the way you want to...

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your suggestion and it works. Now I have a new problem. I want to write any command (e.g. “q” which terminates the underlying process) but it seems that my code is not writing the input of the application. Here is the code:
    StreamWriter processStreamWriter = OCLProcess.StandardInput;
    processStreamWriter.Write("q");
    processStreamWriter.Close();

I also tried using processStreamWriter.WriteLine("q")
 instead of processStreamWriter.Write("q") but it did not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Tony: what you tried should be working! it is probably a bug at that console application, However you can snoop at the console code by using programs like [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1), but you should have some legal authority to do that :) ..

Comment: As i said, the code of oclhashcatlite-32 (console application) is unknown for me, I have no idea in what tech are build that application, snoop that application it’s too hard for me. Would you help me with any other solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tony: If you want to close that application at any stage you can just call `OCLProcess.Kill()`.

Comment: I some actions they are not implemented in native oclhashcatlite-32, this actions require executions of several commands, like “q” for quit, “s” for status, “p” pause and “r” for resume, when I execute the application and starts the task the last line of the oclhashcatlite-32 is” [s]tatus [p]ause [r]esume [q]uit =>” and the prompt wait for one of this letters, that is what are trying to do….
Any idea?